# is there a technical term for applications with different configurations but the same codebase?

Tags: asp.net, oop, architecture, configuration

I hope this is a valid question as me and my team are currently debating how to refer to different applications that have wildly different configurations and behavior but share the same code base.  Is there a technical term for these types of applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are speaking of [multi-tenant](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/multi-tenancy) applications.

Microsoft Office 365 is a multi-tenant application that is made possible via [Multitenant Applications in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/architecture/multi-tenant-web-application-pattern/).

Answer (score 1):

Heroku calls it a 12 Factor App:

http://12factor.net/

Rule #1: One codebase tracked in revision control, many deploys